# SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 at parse (<anonymous>) at tryCallOne

Tags: json, react-native, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, fetch

In my React Native app, I have two different instances where I make an API call and then pass the response to the `json()` method. In the first instance, the promise resolves; in the second, it throws the following error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 at parse () at tryCallOne".

The `response` objects that I pass to `json()` are as follows:

**First instance (successful)**
[image]

**Second instance (unsuccessful)**
[image]

As far as I can tell, the only difference between these two is `x-sourcefiles`, but since they're both strings, I can't imagine that this would cause an error in the `json()` method.

When I've read other people's solutions, normally the problem was that the Response objects they passed to `json()` was not actually JSON (sometimes it was HTML etc). That obviously doesn't apply here since both objects, one of which is successful, are of the same type.

Does anyone have any insight or know how I could approach this?

Comment: Check the response bodies.

Comment: `_bodyBlob` and `_bodyInit` in the JSON objects?

Comment: `_bodyBlob`. Call `text()` on the response instead of `json()` and `console.log` the result.

Comment: In the first case (the one that was successful with json()), text() returns a stringified object with a bunch of properties. In the second case, it just returns the string "value". So this seems to be on the right track. Any idea why text() would have returned a different value, even though the JSON passed in both times was almost the same?

Comment: Because your server, for some reason, decided to respond with `value` instead of a json response.

Comment: The two `response` objects that I shared the screenshots of are what was returned by the server. "value" was what was returned when I passed the second `response` to the text() function.

Comment: Actually, give me one sec...

Comment: The response objects on your screenshots don't show the body though, that's the important part of it.

Comment: I've updated the screenshots. `_bodyBlob._data` in the first is empty, and is non-empty in the second. Do you know what effect that would have?

Comment: I don't know, Blob objects aren't really useful to look at, just use `text()` to get the body as text, and use this to debug the problem. Or just look at the network tab and check the response in there.

Comment: Ok thank you. You've helped me identify where the 'v' is coming from, so I'll work on it based on that. I appreciate it.